# Unique property values between instances of classes in JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, properties

Given an interface `IThing`

```js
interface IThing {
    name: string;
}
```

Is there a way to ensure that classes which implement `IThing` use *unique* values for `name`?

I.e.

```js
class ThingOne implements IThing {
    name = "Name_One"
}

class ThingTwo implements IThing {
    name = "Name_Two"
}
```

Should be allowed, while

```js
class ThingOne implements IThing {
    name = "Name_One"
}

class ThingTwo implements IThing {
    name = "Name_One"
}
```

Should result in a TypeScript error.

The property-values are meant to be readable and hand-written as they describe the object itself so they **can't** be generated.

Comment: TS doesn't try to keep track of which classes have an `implements IThing` clause on them so you'd need to manually maintain a union like `type Things = ThingOne | ThingTwo` before you could even try to get checking.  Would that be a non-starter or are you interested in such an approach?

Comment: The union approach might be feasible, although the project that I'm working on would have > 100 classes which implement `IThing`, and (if it's of any significance) there would be multiple properties which should have a uniqueness constraint.

Comment: It's hard to write something which isn't either illegally circular or redundant or both.  What do you think of [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m33nbm), where you maintain a `ThingRegistry` that cross-references names and class instances?  If that seems promising I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your effort. `ThingRegistry` looks promising although I wouldn't be able to structually differentiate each class, the interface which I've provided in the question is really much larger with additional properties that would have the same constraint as name. 

I've started considering writing a validating script which would collect and instantiate 
all class instances and then report any issues with the definitions. This approach seems shaky though, as each new class definition would have to be manually added to the script.

Comment: Unless you want really weird behavior you're going to need to distinguish the classes structurally; at the very least they should each have a `protected` or `private` member so that the compiler treats them as distinct.  Is the only thing that distinguishes classes from each other the values of those properties?  If so I wonder why you don't just have a single class?  There are other possible approaches to guaranteeing uniqueness but if you need separate class declarations for each then I think anything you do is going to be clunky.

Comment: The classes are distinguished in two ways; through property-values and through the functionality of member functions. Each class serves as a definition for a _statistic_, the definitions hold a `generate` function which is able to compile the specific definition to a set og SQL expressions which can then be used to create a SQL-script that generates a report. The complexity of a given _statistic_ varies greatly, some `generate` functions simply return the properties of the given definition in a correctly formatted string, others do more work as part of the process.

Comment: Creating a single class which would be able to handle _all_ possible cases would result in a single extremely large `generate` function, which I'm trying to avoid such that each _statistic_ and it's "compilation" into SQL may be as self-contained as possible. The class-approach helps with this goal as well as it ensures that all _statistics_ have the same interface, such that the previous layer (in the whole report-generating-process) can handle any combination of _statistics_

Comment: If you happen to make two structurally identical classes (where the string literal types of the properties are all identical, seems unlikely if you have multiple properties but with your example it's essentially inevitable) then the compiler cannot distinguish them; so if you want to avoid this you'll need to add *some* kind of structural difference, even it it serves no purpose to you.

Comment: Anyway, uh, maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w8BMrm) would work better for you, where you maintain a registry of `Thing` classes but the compiler uses a factory function to help catch mistakes.  Would you like to see that written up as an answer?

Comment: I've studied your example a bit and it certainly seems workable. My only real concern is the complexity of the solution, I'd gladly accept a write-up as a solution to the question, would you mind pointing me to some extra ressources such that I could get a better understanding of how it exactly works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't really have any built-in way to ensure uniqueness of properties across different classes, nor does it even keep track of which classes extend/implement other classes/interfaces in a way that the developer can query (the [structural type system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) means that a class can implement an interface even if you don't declare it as such, and so the set of things that implement an interface is potentially infinite, unlike in [nominal type systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system)).

So if you want some guarantee like this, you'll need to significantly refactor your code to press some other TypeScript functionality into service instead, as a workaround.

---

One possible approach is to store your classes in an registry object, and add each class to the object by calling an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) that both checks the new class against the existing ones for correctness/uniqueness, and also records that information in the registry object's type via narrowing.  Maybe like this:

```
interface IThing {
    name: string;
    prop: string;
    generate(): string;
}

type ValidateUniqueThing<TS extends IThing, T extends IThing> = {
    [K in "name" | "prop"]:
    string extends T[K] ? [Error, "Make", K, "readonly PLEASE"] :
    T[K] extends TS[K] ? [Error, "Conflicting ", K, "Property with class named ",
        Extract<TS, { [P in K]: T[K] }>["name"]] :
    T[K]
}

function registerThing<R extends Record<keyof R, IThing>, T extends IThing>(
    registry: { [K in keyof R]: new () => R[K] },
    name: T['name'],
    newThing: new () => (
        T extends ValidateUniqueThing<R[keyof R], T> ? T : ValidateUniqueThing<R[keyof R], T>
    )
): asserts registry is Extract<
    { [K in keyof R | T['name']]: new () => K extends keyof R ? R[K] : T },
    typeof registry
> {
    Object.assign(registry, { [name]: newThing });
}
```

So, the utility type `ValidateUniqueThing<TS, T>` takes a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of existing `Thing` types `TS`, and a candidate for a new addition, `T`.  If `T` is an acceptable addition, then `ValidateUniqueThing<TS, T>` evaluates to just `T`.  Otherwise, the property of `T` that violates a rule will be [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to an incompatible type whose displayed info hopefully gives the developer some information about how to fix the problem.

There are two main possible violations here:

- If the property is of type `string` instead of a [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), then the compiler has no idea what the value will actually be, and it won't be able to guarantee uniqueness.  This usually happens when you initialize a property with a string literal without marking the property as [`readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#readonly), so the incompatible type mentions `readonly` (but you could change this to whatever you want).
- If the property already exists in the union of existing literal types for the same property in the other registered classes, then the compiler has caught a uniqueness violation.  The incompatible type tries to figure out which class already used the name, using [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union).

The `registerThing()` function takes the `registry` object as its first argument, the `name` property of the new class instances as its second argument, and the `newThing` class to be registered as its third argument.  It is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `R`, the mapping of class `name`s to their instance types, and `T` the instance type of the new class.  The types of `registry` and `name` are straightforward mappings and [indexings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into `R` and `T`.  The type of `newThing` depends on `ValidateUniqueThing<R[keyof R], T>` (where `R[keyof R]` is the union of already-registered `IThing` instance types) in such a way that if `newThing` is valid, then the type matches it (it just becomes `new () => T`), but if it is *not* valid, then the type doesn't match (it becomes `new () => X` where `X` is the incompatible type from `ValidateUniqueThing` above) and you get an error message.

And because `registerThing()` is an assertion function, its return type `asserts registry is ...` will cause the registry object's type to narrow after the function is called.  The type it narrows to is just the existing registry object type with a new property added corresponding to the `newThing` argument.

---

Okay, let's see it in action.

First we make an empty registry object:

```
const _Things = {};
// const _Things: {}
```

I prefaced that name with `_` because once it's all done we will copy it to a new `const` so that we are sure that it's ready for use everywhere.  Let's register a class:

```
registerThing(_Things, "ThingOne", class ThingOne {
    readonly name = "ThingOne";
    readonly prop = "Prop";
    generate() {
        return this.name + " " + this.prop
    }
}); // okay

_Things;
/* const _Things: {
    ThingOne: new () => ThingOne;
} */
```

That succeeded, and now we can see that `_Things`'s type has been changed to reflect the addition.  Let's do that again:

```
registerThing(_Things, "ThingTwo", class ThingTwo {
    readonly name = "ThingTwo";
    readonly prop = "PropTwo";
    generate() {
        return this.name + " " + this.prop
    }
}); // okay

_Things;
/* const _Things: {
    ThingOne: new () => ThingOne;
    ThingTwo: new () => ThingTwo;
} */
```

Still looks good.  Okay, now let's make a mistake:

```
registerThing(_Things, "ThingThree", class ThingThree { // error!
    // '[Error, "Conflicting ", "prop", "Property with class named ", "ThingTwo"]
    readonly name = "ThingThree";
    readonly prop = "PropTwo";
    generate() {
        return "wha"
    }
});
```

Uh oh, we got an error.  If you squint at the error message, it says that `prop` conflicts with `ThingTwo`.  Let's fix that:

```
registerThing(_Things, "ThingThree", class ThingThree {
    readonly name = "ThingThree";
    readonly prop = "PropThree";
    generate() {
        return "wha"
    }
}); // okay
```

And let's make another mistake:

```
registerThing(_Things, "ThingFour", class ThingFour { // error!
    // [Error, "Make", "name", "readonly PLEASE"]
    name = "ThingFour";
    readonly prop = "PropFour";
    generate() {
        return ""
    }
});
```

Uh oh, we got an error.  Squinting reveals that `name` is not `readonly` and therefore is of type `string` instead of `"ThingFour"`.  Let's fix that:

```
registerThing(_Things, "ThingFour", class ThingFour {    
    readonly name = "ThingFour";
    readonly prop = "PropFour";
    generate() {
        return ""
    }
}); // okay
```

Great.  Now we copy the completed `_Things` to `Things`:

```
const Things = _Things;
/*
const Things: {
    ThingOne: new () => ThingOne;
    ThingTwo: new () => ThingTwo;
    ThingThree: new () => ThingThree;
    ThingFour: new () => ThingFour;
}*/
```

which has all the props we want.  And to use the classes, we just index into `Things`:

```
function foo() {
    const thing2 = new Things.ThingTwo();
    // const thing2: ThingTwo
    console.log(thing2.generate())
}
```

So, that works!  The reason why I copied `_Things` to `Things` is that, like all [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) effects, the narrowing done in assertion functions does not persist across function boundaries.  So inside `foo()`, you'd find that `_Things` would look completely empty:

```
function foo() {
    const thing2 = new _Things.ThingTwo(); // error!
    // Property 'ThingTwo' does not exist on type '{}'.
}
```

That's unfortunate, but to prevent that the compiler would have to do a lot of extra effort to try to figure out when `foo()` was called with respect to when `_Things` was configured, and that's not feasible (see [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) for a discussion about the general issue).  It's easy enough to get to a place where the compiler knows the narrowed type is valid, and then copy to a `const` whose type is the same no matter where you use it.

---

So, hooray, that whole thing works.  It's complicated, and maybe too complicated to be useful to you.  Possibly some other approach would be more to your liking, but everything I can think of (including this approach) will involve some kind of circularity, redundancy, ugliness, or "non-locality" of errors.

By that I mean that you will catch uniqueness violations, but the error message will not be close to the location where the violation occurred.  For example, if you built some kind of manually maintained union of all classes (which is redundant) and then wrote a type that probed it for uniqueness violations, the error would be somewhere near that type, and not necessarily close to the class with the problem.

So I think this will ultimately come down to a matter of taste and applicability to use cases, as is often the situation with workarounds.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUAWoDmyDeAsAFACQIcAthAFzIDOYUuA3CaQA5QD2HdjzEDjZkcEENDiQAFAEp+TViQC+JEmACeHFADU4AG2AATKRACqIYAEcArhCy4APOgDKyCAA9III-TQOhABpkdHcvcV9-bCEAPmQAXgJ2AG0AaWRQZAAiCmos5AAfbK5eLIBdGnYBXDDvSPQ0suQAfmRkgFEoHihgrIBZOABrCCzg1N6oCDgjbhB9DWQABQAZdoBBF3by5EqyBtSmzzq-V0aWts7u3oBhWZhDBDAa0eRx7MWebShNZAB3YDAmGQCH0cHoflyECM2UC7FI7S8UEQYGcLmC+DaiwyIFeFRCZ2UMWSOSoIzKTV2pH2ZRUJBgNhAj2As2QkxwwEY0ACOEcACVahE-LyIAhuFAjI5hhpuDBkLzghhojgYsFQkdBVFcDFpOw2RymBo6Bi0tjkFKZXK8RJfsg5Ak4ryCbCyJC6A0AOSQ91lZ3kCC-bl0a222T221wtXhHx+PSGEyQCzWOzcvnJc2y3k+kJxVqhOix4ymRO2exK1Ppy2qmLsWQkeTIMH0aBgPx6gQLDnIBFMZGOdjG9KZCv8ooer3koP+kNh9Lq6NmiDSjPnR0HHYhZDKX2abQWtsGkhxIhkADyACMAFYisAAOkbwBwIGk+6gGnRbUhVv93M3shEqmIEhRRARhkAAfW5PxEnwZQRAAejg4FZlAiClXoI0AJIfcuSVaRUNwehem5E8JBeEFGxCJUSJQY9SEmaZZnmZBIQSbJiNIkQ6KmGY5gWEoOFYrIPlKTixAkJEZFDWiuLAGwoBxQEORvFiAGpsnUtTFPoG9+PYADlD-ZAEOQbhBjgDQ1GIfChHoeCACokJAsBwMgo12HY2hmKnO14jiDz-2QOy4Ms7CoG5PDIKIpV0F+bgyNBcFKNwGLuCSMh6J4piWMSLJuRSrJOIyxi+M+QThI4fLRPESRJLS0gZLkhTsG01T1PyTTmp0z49JUQzjNM8zLOsnBbJIOCHOAlDXLqjzJxtHy-KoiROLy2K5unXykqEFKAqCyzxqwiB2U5MLcOGwi2OizBJhGYJyMSvLrogGijMQ6BugAQnYYz3Q6LoxRuO4HieIQYWKT4XiEz5mwWf5AWBBKIVJaFIdWuKaXS7jiuY0lBMem6Ct1LHeOQfiys+Sr2DEmqIDtaTJlk+Tsl+TA4CyHriAMkQ9sA4gDuIZBWSO-UcNwCK0Ki3AADFuDk+KKO5GW5IIV73H+qAvrIYy-qubIBmGSHIUhoqSZWdZNnKdhssu6XZagQnMYYkmyZy8qlftqrxNMOm4QZxrsnZsh9L-EgecO47IFOsXzsl7antuhGFaum66pNrLcZy-HnodrinaYl33gp+Oc+piTaak32IEZnEshZtmOa51WBos3nQvCmObaEd35YepV3bSom84Wa3cr7u2c7TkreHJ3hu89mmfbIBqmayQPSGDlgm7MlugOQ5zINY877N3pytpGty9iWzzgwWs-qJW6K1q8+bQ02tGH+S+P1tvrOIA-ru7bf1fotW2cl-xh15vSRkTwWQwG4NwRepBjKTWcopIQAAmViwZzo3jRnITexl3pik1kgxC5UYbIHdGjd0yAZgQAhNwZynh9QmQUloFA7oYLuhvNIdBABmPhABOWsZAUHIDQTgTBiRgyQVwY-BBhlvqITERI9Bbp5HsEmtwfQEAbz6G4DgaQqibyl29rIERyggA)

Answer (score 0):

I see only decision with using Set to track unique names

```html
let usedNames = new Set<string>();
class ThingOne implements IThing {
    name: string;
    constructor(name: string) {
        if (usedNames.has(name)) {
            throw new Error(`Name "${name}" has already been used.`);
        }
        usedNames.add(name);
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```